# How to make Subdomains identified as separate sites by Search Engines

Tags: subdomain, seo

I have a domain name and a live website.
I want to create some subdomains so that they appear as separate websites in Search engines.

For Example take Blogspot. 
**x.blogspot.com and y.blogspot.com are separate websites.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is normal behavior. I am not sure what your question is exactly. But here goes.

I am going to assume you are using Apache and host your DNS.

Create the sub-domain on your server however you need. For Apache, this would be almost exactly like any other domains website. You can find the configuration files in /etc/apache2/sites-available or /etc/local/apache2/sites-available. If there is a website already on the web server, you will see the configuration file named something like mydomain.com.conf. Use this file as an example and create your sub-domains. Create a file for each sub-domain like sub-domain.domain.com and cut and paste the contents of your original domain configuration into each. You will need to change some directives.

1] Change your ServerName to something like sub-domain.domain.com to reflect your sub-domain.

2] Remove ServerAlias.

3] Create a root directory for your sub-domain change DocumentRoot and .

4] You may need to change your log file locations as well.

You may have a control panel for this.

Create an entry in your DNS server for the sub-domain. Using the same IP address as the parent domain is fine depending upon your set-up. I am sure it will work okay assuming that all of the sites will be hosted on the same system. You will need an A record for each sub-domain. I cannot tell you how to create the record for your system. I am assuming you will have a control panel for this.

That is it.

Search engines treat all sub-domains websites as separate sites and separate from the parent domain.

Comment: Good luck with it! Add a comment if you have any issues.

Comment: Google does *not* treat subdomains as separate websites

Comment: With respect John- each web site on a sub-domain is a separate site from the parent domain site and any other sub-domain site. This is well known.

Comment: Hi! I followed Closetnoc's instructions, Thank you very much! Now I have both mydomain.com and sub.mydomain.com indexed in Google and I'm managing them in Google Webmaster tools as two seperate websites.

Comment: Good News!! I am always glad to help where I can. That is why I am here.